# root always still null on my binary tree

Tags: search, tree

```
import java.io.*;

class treeNode {

    int data;
    treeNode left = null;
    treeNode right = null;
    treeNode parent = null;

    treeNode (int value)
    {
        data = value;
    }
}



class treeNodes {

    treeNode root = null;         

    void insert (treeNode node)
    {
        if (root == null) // the value of root is always null
        {           
            root = node;            
            return;
        }

        treeNode cur = null;
        treeNode father = null;

        while (cur != null)
        {
            father = cur;
            if (cur.data > node.data)
                cur = cur.left;
            else
                cur = cur.right;
        }

        if (father.data > node.data)
            father.left = node;
        else
            father.right = node;

        node.parent = father;
    }

    void walkInorder (treeNode n)
    {
        if (n == null)
            return;

        walkInorder (n.left);
        System.out.print (n.data + " ");
        walkInorder (n.right);
    }
}

class binarySearchTree {

    public static void main (String [] args) {   

        treeNodes obj1 = new treeNodes ( );     

        System.out.println ("============ Array Elements ============"); 

        int A[] = {3, 5, 7, 9, 8, 6};

        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            treeNode node = new treeNode (A[i]);
            treeNodes obj = new treeNodes ( );
            obj.insert(node);                     
        }      

        System.out.println ("\n============ Inorder ============");
        System.out.println (obj1.root.data);
        obj1.walkInorder (obj1.root);        

    }
}
```

i'm tried to make binary tree and when i send the first value to insert function it should change the value of root

In my case the root never change can someone tell me why and how can i solve it

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `for` loop, for each item in your array, you are creating a new `treeNodes` instance. Whenever you create a new instance, `root` is set to `null`.
Try making the following change to your `for` loop:

```
    treeNodes obj = new treeNodes();

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        treeNode node = new treeNode(A[i]);            
        obj.insert(node);                     
    }
```

This way, every step of your loop will use the same `treeNodes` instance, and the root node will correctly be set. There are other problems with your code, but part of learning is experimenting. So, go ahead, fix the issue above and let us know how it goes.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the answer above is not completely right. Yes, you'll be creating a new treeNodes instance everytime the loop goes to the next element in your array, but that would mean you were creating new trees with only one element, so the root would not be null.
The roots you are trying to print, in the other hand, are null in fact, but thats because you did not insert any element in the tree you are trying to print.
You tried to walk in order the tree OBJ1, and you didnt insert anything into this tree. You should try to walk in order the tree OBJ.

The answer above is right, you need to make that fix, so you will insert the array elements into only one tree, and then fix this issue i explained.

Comment: Actually, I did not say we were creating trees with no elements. I said that anytime you create a new `treeNodes` instance, the `root` is set to `null`. And it is correct. The code that "creates a tree with only one element" is inside the `main` method, not in `treeNodes` constructor.